# Handling interface builder sizing in Xcode has changed

Tags: ios, interface-builder, storyboard

I've started a new iOS project and I was surprised to see that the way to handle metrics for controllers has changed.

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: after]

Is that a new Apple feature or have I done something wrong? I've have installed cocos2D's template today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature?  Well, it's intentional, at least.  :-)

It can be turned off, if you prefer, by selecting the File Inspector for the xib or storyboard and unchecking the "Use Autolayout" option.

Comment: Thank you but I will adapt myself if it's intentional :). Thank you for your answer !